# Use return total number of pages in tcpdf as new function parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

I want to show total pages of tcpdf in a word, e.g : 7 as Seven.

I tried to use $pdf->getAliasNbPages() as parameter in new function, but it not work.

Here's the function

```
function terbilang($x){
$abil = array('', 'satu', 'dua', 'tiga', 'empat', 'lima', 'enam', 'tujuh', 'delapan', 'sembilan', 'sepuluh', 'sebelas');
if($x < 12){
    return ' ' . $abil[$x];
}elseif($x < 20){
    return terbilang($x - 10) . 'belas';
}elseif($x < 100){
    return terbilang($x / 10) . ' puluh' . terbilang($x % 10);
}elseif($x < 200){
    return ' seratus' . terbilang($x - 100);
}elseif($x < 1000){
    return terbilang($x / 100) . ' ratus' . terbilang($x % 100);
}elseif($x < 2000){
    return ' seribu' . terbilang($x - 1000);
}elseif($x < 1000000){
    return terbilang($x / 1000) . ' ribu' . terbilang($x % 1000);
}elseif($x < 1000000000){
    return terbilang($x / 1000000) . ' juta' . terbilang($x % 1000000);
}
```

}

Code run well with dummy input, but not work with $pdf->getAliasNbPages(). Function also work with $pdf->getNumPages().

Any solution ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share the exception\output\errors you do get

Comment: hi, TommySM, sorry for late reply...

there is no error, script run well, just don't have any output (blank) like no data.